# Select a random hyperplane

Tags: probability

How can one generate a uniformly random $n$ dimensional hyperplane which passes through the origin?

In 2d it seems one can pick an angle at random and draw a line from the origin at that angle.  I am not sure what the right thing to do in higher dimensions is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a point $u$ on the unit sphere $S^n$ of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ uniformly randomly and consider the random hyperplane $H=\{x\in\mathbb R^{n+1}\mid\langle x,u\rangle=0\}$.

**Edit:** One can also consider $H$ the set of $(x_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n+1}$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sqrt{-\log u_{2k-1}}\cdot\cos(\pi u_{2k})\cdot x_k=0,$$ where $(u_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant 2n+2}$ is i.i.d. uniform on $(0,1)$.

For a refinement allowing to use roughly $n+1$ or $n+2$ uniform random variables instead of $2n+2$, see @HaraldHanche-Olsen's first comment.

Comment: And the easiest way to do that is probably to pick a random vector from a Gaussian distribution and normalize it. Note that you can pick two independent normally distributed values $x$ and $y$ at a time by taking $x=\sqrt{-\ln u} \cdot\cos 2\pi v$, $y=\sqrt{-\ln u} \cdot\sin2\pi v$ with $u$, $v$ independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen's remark is interesting since one does not even need to normalize the Gaussian random vector. (But $\sqrt{-\log u}$, not $\log u$.)

Comment: Ah, forgot about the square root, thanks. I fixed it since it was still within the edit window.

Comment: This is slightly OT but is there an efficient way to find any point on the hyperplane which is not the origin?

Comment: Lembik, perhaps pose this as a separate question?

Comment: @Travis Good point. Thank you.

Comment: Surely, that's standard linear algebra? Set all but one coordinate to what ever you wish, then solve for the last one.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Standard linear algebra is on topic for math.se :) Thank you.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Sorry, I was busy adding (a version of) your remark to the post hence I cannot modify my first comment to you anymore.

Comment: No problem. The context makes clear what happened.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen did you choose the Gaussian distribution out of convenience or is there another reason? I'm saying this because I'm not sure why this would sample a point uniformly, as coordinates of the vector are more likely to be around the Gaussian's mean.

Comment: @synack the point here is that the multivariate Gaussian distribution is rotationally symmetric, i.e., invariant under the orthogonal group. And when you then normalise the samples, you have a rotationally symmetric distribution on the sphere, which more or less by definition means it's uniform.

Comment: great explanation. thank you, @HaraldHanche-Olsen For the record, it seems it is the only distribution with such property: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/255417/40817